# How important is it to check return values when using the Python C API?

Tags: python, c, memory-management

It seems that everytime I call a function that returns a PyObject*, I have to add four lines of error checking. Example:

```
py_fullname = PyObject_CallMethod(os, "path.join", "ss", folder, filename);
if (!py_fullname) {
    Py_DECREF(pygame);
    Py_DECREF(os);
    return NULL;
}
image = PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs(pygame, "image.load", py_fullname, NULL);
Py_DECREF(py_fullname);
if (!image) {
    Py_DECREF(pygame);
    Py_DECREF(os);
    return NULL;
}
image = PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs(image, "convert", NULL);
if (!image) {
    Py_DECREF(pygame);
    Py_DECREF(os);
    return NULL;
}
```

Am I missing something? Is there a better way to do this? This has the added problem that I may forget all the stuff I'm supposed to `Py_DECREF()`.

Comment: Why don't you use Cython + C ? The only case I encountered where I had to use the Python C API was in some threaded C code called from Cython that sometimes had to call pure Python code (it represented ~10 lines of Python C API)... In all other cases I've been able to wrap the pure C code with Cython entirely, and never worried about the C API.

Comment: That's interesting, I didn't know about it. Still, this is more like an excuse to practice a bit of C and make it do something useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's why `goto` is alive (though not entirely well;-) in C coding (as opposed to C++ and other languages that support exceptions): it's the only decent way to NOT have such repeated blocks of termination all over the mainline of your code -- a conditional forward jump to `errorexit` at each return-value check, with a label `errorexit:` that does the decrefs (and file closes, and whatever else you need to do at termination) and the `return NULL`.

Comment: "cosmetics" like `#define EXCIFZERO(x) if (!x) goto errorexit` can help

Answer (score 3):

Here are two ways I might write that code, influenced by my experience writing in two heavily macro-ised pseudo-assembler languages, one of which wasn't C. I've moved the deref of fullname, not because it's wrong in your code, but because I want to demonstrate how you handle a longer-lived resource in both schemes. So imagine that "fullname" is going to be needed again later in the routine:

#### Arrow code

```
result = NULL;
py_fullname = PyObject_CallMethod(os, "path.join", "ss", folder, filename);
if (py_fullname) {
    image = PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs(pygame, "image.load", py_fullname, NULL);
    if (image) {
        image = PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs(image, "convert", NULL);
        result = // something to do with image, presumably.
    }
    Py_DECREF(py_fullname);
}
Py_DECREF(pygame);
Py_DECREF(os);
return result;
```

The way this game is played, is that whenever you call a function which returns a resource, you check the return value immediately (or perhaps after freeing some resource which is no longer required, as in your example code), and the block corresponding to a successful call *must* either release the resource, or assign it to a return value, or actually return it, before the block is exited. This will usually be either in the second line of the block, after it has been used in the first line, or else in the last line of the block.

It's called "arrow code" because if you make 5 or 6 such calls in a function, you end up with 5 or 6 levels of indentation, and your function looks like a "turn right" sign. When this happens you either refactor, or you go against your every Pythonic instinct, use tabs for indentation, and reduce the tab stops ;-)

#### Goto

```
result = NULL;
py_fullname = PyObject_CallMethod(os, "path.join", "ss", folder, filename);
if (!py_fullname) goto cleanup_pygame

image = PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs(pygame, "image.load", py_fullname, NULL);
if (!image) goto cleanup_fullname

image = PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs(image, "convert", NULL);
result = // something to do with image, presumably.

cleanup_fullname:
    Py_DECREF(py_fullname);
cleanup_pygame:
    Py_DECREF(pygame);
    Py_DECREF(os);
    return result;
```

This goto code is structurally identical to the arrow code, just less indented and easier to mess up and jump to the wrong label. In some circumstances you will clean up different resources on success from what you clean up on failure (for instance if you're constructing and returning something, then on failure you need to clean up whatever you've done so far, but on success you only clean up what you're not returning). Those are the circumstances where the goto code is a clear win over the arrow code, because you can have separate cleanup paths for the two cases, but they still look the same, appear together at the end of the routine, and perhaps even share code. So you might end up with something like this:

```
result = NULL;
helper = allocate_something;
if (!helper) goto return_result;

result = allocate_something_else;
if (!result) goto error_return; // OK, result is already NULL, but it makes the point

result->contents = allocate_another_thing;
if (!result->contents) goto error_cleanup_result;

result->othercontents = allocate_last_thing;
if (!result->othercontents) goto error_cleanup_contents;

free_helper:
    free(helper);
return_result:
    return result;

error_cleanup_contents:
    free(result->contents);
error_cleanup_result:
    free(result);
error_return;
    result = NULL;
    goto free_helper;
```

Yes, it's horrible, and Python or C++ programmers will be physically sick at the sight of it. If I never have to write code like this again, I won't be all that disappointed. But as long as you have a systematic scheme for how resources are cleaned up, you should always know exactly what error label to jump to when something goes wrong, and that error label should "know" to clean up all resources that have been allocated so far. Doing it in reverse order allows fall-through to share the code. And once you're used to it, it's reasonably easy to do two things: first follow the path from any given error label, to the exit, and confirm that everything which should be freed is freed. Second, see the *difference* between two error cases, and confirm that this is the correct difference between the error-handling needed, because the difference is precisely to free the thing that was allocated in between the jumps to those labels.

That said, a semi-decent optimising compiler will common up the code for the error cases in your example. It's just easier to make a mistake when you have code copy-and-pasted about the place like that, especially when you modify it later.

Comment: It's interesting that this haven't been up-voted at all. It's a good write up on how cleaning before return are commonly done in C.

Answer (score 2):

This is the C API. If you code in C only, you may have to live with it, but if your application is coded in C++, you might want a take a look at a [C++/Python wrapper](http://davidf.sjsoft.com/mirrors/mcmillan-inc/scxx.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the reasons why C++ introduces exception handling and RAII. Assuming you can use C++, you can create a function that invokes the C function, tests the result, and throws an exception if an error occurred. That way, you can call the wrapper without any checks... if an error occurs, it will throw the exception. However, there is no need to reinvent the wheel, check out the [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/python/doc/) library.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't see it often I consider this a good solution for C programmers ("the goto with tie"):

```
result = NULL;
// make sure all variables are initialized

do
{
    py_fullname = PyObject_CallMethod(os, "path.join", "ss", folder, filename);
    if (!py_fullname)
    {
        // some additional error handling here
        // write a trace message with __FILE__ and __LINE__
        break;
    }

    image = PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs(pygame, "image.load", py_fullname, NULL);
    if (!image)
    {
        // some additional error handling here
        break;
    }

    image = PyObject_CallMethodObjArgs(image, "convert", NULL);

    result = // something to do with image, presumably.
} while (true);

if (py_fullname)
    Py_DECREF(py_fullname);
if (pygame)
    Py_DECREF(pygame);
if (os)
    Py_DECREF(os);

return result;
```

There are several advantages:

1. Only one exit in the function - you can set a breakpoint at the end and be sure it works
2. Cleanup code is not repeated
3. No cascaded ifs
4. Error checking is done as early as possible and points exactly to the problem (trace message)
5. Initializing all variables is a good idea anyhow so why not use it in the cleanup section?

I recommend to write some macros in order to unify the code:

```
#define CATCH_BEGIN     do {
#define CATCH_END       } while (1!=1);
#define CLEANUP_VOID(function,var) {if (var != NULL) { function(var); var = NULL;}}
```

This allows to cleanup at the end like this:

```
CLEANUP_VOID(Py_DECREF, py_fullname)
CLEANUP_VOID(Py_DECREF, pygame)
CLEANUP_VOID(Py_DECREF, os)
```